# Java oop conception suggestion

Tags: oop, uml

I am currently devlopping a web application,in which i have company class and contact class which exchange emails,so i want to know if i can make email as association class between contact and company ?Like that ?
By the way in the other part of my diagram i have mail exchange between departments whch are part of the company,so may i add another email association class between departments?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can. But why? An association class is used if you want to introduce certain functionality connected with the relation between both connected classes. Or if you need a trapeze-relation (e.g. if you need to mark each email with attributes like for the purpose, private or business etc.). In your case, you just have `0..*` emails per `Contact`. So I'd simply model that as attribute of `Contact` with multiplicity of `0..*`. Simple as that.